# FadeIn() / FadeOut() the page scrolls before the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following methods to fade in and fade out a section of my page:

```
//function shows more reviews
function ShowMoreReviews() {
    $(document.getElementById('extraReviews')).fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById('showReviewsIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-upload";
    document.getElementById('btnShowReviews').onclick = function() { ShowLessReviews() };
    document.getElementById('hideReviewsText').innerHTML = "Show less";
}
//function shows less reviews
function ShowLessReviews() {
    $(document.getElementById('extraReviews')).fadeOut(1000);
    document.getElementById('showReviewsIcon').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-download";
    document.getElementById('btnShowReviews').onclick = function() { ShowMoreReviews() };
    document.getElementById('hideReviewsText').innerHTML = "Show more";
}
```

The "extraReviews" div is at the very bottom of the page, when the fade in method is called, the section is faded in but because it is out of the user's view, they don't see the animation and there's just a jump:

https://i.gyazo.com/531382f82b711c6a86c1d4e245e16a12.mp4 (video)

When the fade out method is called, the page jumps to where the finishing position will be whilst the animation runs:

https://i.gyazo.com/e24869497b5a8098267e7eea9184b3f6.mp4

The #extraReviews div is hidden upon page load

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('#extraReviews').hide();
}
```

Comment: $(document.getElementById('extraReviews')).fadeIn(1000); = $('#extraReviews').fadeIn(1000); And if you are using Jquery, do you add the lib to your files?

Comment: @Roy I do call it in my layout partial, If I scroll down when the fadeOut is being called, I can see the animation

Comment: Maybe you have a href="#" and it jumps to top. If is it, put href="javascript:void(0)"

Comment: @Roy that's exactly it! Thank you! I did have it set to javascript:; before but changed it!

Comment: Nice!, good coding!